# So I'm stuck in the Mongolian Tower in Stick of Truth somehow. Help no exit in floor under boss fight!

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

So I fought the Mongolian herd on the top of the tower. I took the exit and it brought me one level down. But there's no exit down from that level?! Is it because I already set off all the fireworks before I went up?

Comment: If you've figured it out, I'd recommend telling us what the answer is.  You can help more readers!

Comment: Please don't edit the question to say you've figured it out - since you have, perhaps leave an answer in case others get stuck?

Comment: Sorry thought I did. The barrel is on the left hand balcony. Behind there.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess you already figured it out but for all the other players having the same problem:
The exit is on the far left of this platform behind the pillar

Answer (score 1):

The original questioner figured out his own question, and edited his answer into his question.

**The apparent solution was roughly:**

The barrel is on the left hand balcony.  I just didn't remember where it was and behind the barrel is easy to miss.